# Passing state from Home page to Navbar and conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, state, navbar

I need to render certain `<div>` in Navbar if state in another component is TRUE

This is my Home.js page where I change state to TRUE after button is clicked:

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      competitors: false,
      // intervalId: 0,
    };
  };

  clickedCompetitors(){
    this.setState({ competitors : !this.state.competitors });
  }

render() {
return(
  <div className="col-md-4">
       <Link to="competitors" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
     onClick={() => this.clickedCompetitors()}>Competiror's Review</Link>
  </div> 
 )
}
```

Now I need to pass the state to the Navbar Component.
But the problem is that I have to call it. Right?
Like so:

```
  <Navbar dataFromHome={() => this.clickedCompetitors()} />
```

The thing is that I called it already in App.js and if I call it again at the Home page it appears twice.
Anyway then I am trying to get the access to the state at Navbar, so I can apply my conditional rendering:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Home from "./Home";
class Navbar extends Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false
  };

toggleOpen = () => this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });

dataFromHome = () => {
    return this.props.dataFromHome
  }

render(){
const trufish = (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="dropdown" onClick={this.toggleOpen}>
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle"
            type="button"
            id="dropdownMenuButton"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            >
            Countries
          </button>
          <div className={menuClass} aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">

            <Link to="/" className="dropdown-item">
              China
            </Link>

            <Link to="/" className="dropdown-item">
              Hong Kong
            </Link>

            <Link to="/indonesia" className="dropdown-item">
              Indonesia
            </Link>

            <Link to="/" className="dropdown-item">
              Japan
            </Link>

            <Link to="/" className="dropdown-item">
              Malaysia
            </Link>

            <Link to="/" className="dropdown-item">
              Saudi Arabia
            </Link>

            <Link to="/" className="dropdown-item">
              Singapore
            </Link>

            <Link to="/" className="dropdown-item">
              South Korea
            </Link>

            <Link to="/" className="dropdown-item">
              Philippines
            </Link>

            <Link to="/" className="dropdown-item">
              UAE
            </Link>

            <Link to="/" className="dropdown-item">
              Vietnam
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>

      </Fragment>
    )
return(

  { this.dataFromHome() ? trufish : ""}
 )
}
```

My problems are:

- 1)Not sure if my state is passing
- 2)My condition does not look like    working
- 3)I have to call `<Navbar>` at Home page to pass the state

Answer (score 1):

If your `NavBar` component is in `Home`, you can pass your function down to the NavBar component as onClick function and also the related state for conditional rendering.

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      competitors: false,
      // intervalId: 0,
    };
  };

  // this can be onClick function for changing state in NavBar component
  clickedCompetitors(){
    this.setState({ competitors : !this.state.competitors });
  }

render() {
const {competitors} = this.state;
return(
  <div className="col-md-4">
       <Navbar dataFromHome={this.clickedCompetitors} condition={competitors}/>
       <Link to="competitors" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
     onClick={() => this.clickedCompetitors()}>Competiror's Review</Link>
  </div> 
 )
}
```

For render problem

```
render(){
   const {dataFromHome} = this.props;
   {dataFromHome() && (<Fragment>
        <div className="dropdown" onClick={this.toggleOpen}>
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle"
            type="button"
            id="dropdownMenuButton"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            >}
          //other logic...
        )
}
```

Comment: Yes I know it and was doing it, but I need to avoid doing it. As I have to call Navbar only once in App.js which I have done already.
If I call it again on Home page it appears twice.
Also my condition seems not working still

Comment: Why would you need to call the function in ```Home```? if the state you needed should be shared around components, just put your state upwards. Besides ```NavBar```, what else does ```App``` hold?

Comment: For render problem, I have updated my answer. See whether it works

Comment: I am calling the function in Home.js because there is my button which changes state from false to true. If the state is true only in that case Navbar renders my Fragment.
I don't think that I can set state depending on button somewhere higher as Home and Navbar at the same level and the highes is App.js where I have only my Routers and Navbar above all of them.
Regarding the solution of render, does not seem working for me as you didn't mention if else statment

Comment: For the first problem, is it possible to put code on fiddle? I would like to help you figure out this problem as well. For the rendering problem, besides the method you use (ternary operator), there is another way (short-circuit evaluation) can be used for distinguishing conditions. Basically, using && means if the first condition is true, do the latter thing.

Comment: Hi I had some logic issues which I fixed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61950646/how-to-save-conditional-rendering-in-navbar-using-true-false-state-of-another-co
Can you please have a look it, if you have time